# Ethernet-Speed only 100 Mbps

Tags: internet, pop-os

I'm currently using Pop!_OS and unfortunately I've encountered an issue with my Ethernet-Connection:

My Internet-Speed on Pop!_OS is capped at 100 Mbit/s. My Internet-Speed from my ISP is 200 Mbps in Downstream and 8 Mbps Upstream so that is not the problem. Also before Pop!_OS I used Windows and I had 200 Mbps Downstream and 8 Mbps Upstream there.
It is a wired connection too so it should be pretty stable most of the time.

The Ethernet-Controller in my motherboard (MSI B550-A Pro) is the Realtek® 8111H Gigabit LAN controller.

I already did some research but couldn't really find a solution.

I hope you can help me!

Edit: The ethtool says the following:

```
ethtool enp42s0
Settings for enp42s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP    MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: on
    master-slave cfg: preferred slave
    master-slave status: slave
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: external
    MDI-X: Unknown
netlink error: Operation not permitted
    Link detected: yes
```

**Edit: I fixed it by disabling IPv6 in the Network-Settings and rebooting. Now it shows 1000 Mbit/s instead of 100 Mbit/s and also full speed is there now.**

**Edit 2: Here is the terminal after I disabled IPv6:**

```
ethtool enp42s0
Settings for enp42s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP    MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                        1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                        1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                     100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                     1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: on
    master-slave cfg: preferred slave
    master-slave status: master
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: external
    MDI-X: Unknown
netlink error: Operation not permitted
    Link detected: yes
```

Comment: It looks like you found a solution to your issue. Would you be able to post it as an answer rather than as an edit to the question? See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer  However, if you can't describe why what you did resolved the issue, then we might instead opt for closing your question as "off-topic; problem went away".

Comment: If you re-enable IPv6 and reboot, are you again capped at 100 Mbit/s?

Comment: yeah IPv6/IPv4 is one layer "above" your link speed, I bet that it works now is just a lucky coincidence, not an actual solution.

Comment: What is the category of the cable or its state of conservation? Seems like a flaky cable.

Comment: The state of the cable is pretty good. On Windows I never had any problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                     100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
```

This is what the remote end has reported it will support. Since there is no `1000baseT/Full` option, here the device at the far end of the network cable is telling it won't support a gigabit connection.

When you disabled IPv6, did you also change the network cable in any way? Did you, for example, plug it into a different port in the modem? Perhaps only some of its ports are gigabit capable.

Comment: I only disabled IPv6. I didn't change the network cable in any way. Yesterday I then enabled IPv6 again and it stayed at 1000 Mbit/s but today it downgraded again to 100 Mbit/s so I disabled it today again and it's now at 1000 Mbit/s again.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried disabling ipv6 and that didn't work for me.
My issue was caused by "powersave" tuning profile which was putting NIC in 100MBps mode.

To check your tuning profile run `sudo tuned-adm active`. If this returns "powersave" then change it to the default `sudo tuned-adm profile balanced`

Comment: what is the `tuned-adm` command? it shows `sudo: tuned-adm: command not found` when trying to run it

Comment: It can be found in the `tuned` package on ubuntu